# 'Connection timed out' (Could not send message) on SOAP request (but service isn't down)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, connection-timeout

I'm getting 'Connection timed out' on a SOAP request to another company's webservice. I have used wsimport to create the Java classes from the wsdl. I don't think its a problem on the other companies end, because they have provided me with a little app which uses the webservice to quickly test what results I should get when I code it myself, and that works fine.

In the example below I am trying to get data about 'Staff' at a school ...

```
OtherCompanyWebService ws = new OtherCompanyWebService();
OtherCompanyWebServicePortType port = ws.getOtherCompanyWebServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint();
ServiceRequest serviceRequest = makeMyServiceRequest();
Staff staff = port.getStaffData(serviceRequest).getStaff().getValue();
```

On the final line of code, I get the following error ...

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:199)
        at $Proxy52.getStaffData(Unknown Source)
        at uk.co.txttools.rm.service.RmServiceImpl.runRmJob(RmServiceImpl.java:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy12.runRmJob(Unknown Source)
        at uk.co.txttools.rm.quartz.RmJob.execute(RmJob.java:41)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:296)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:242)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:178)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:975)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:916)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1019)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1834)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1792)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1852)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:593)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
```

**Edit 1:** it appears that the endpoints in the wsdl file are internal addresses. This is why I cant connect. Do I need to set these endpoints to something else in my code somehow???

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the edit to the question, the endpoints in the wsdl need changing (even though this sounds crazy to me). This can be done as follows ...

```
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
          BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
          "https://blah/blah/blah");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have faced similar issue; The wsdl can be accessible from any whr inside the company(Through browser).But while calling webservice(through client code) throws time out Exception. In that case what i did ,i raised a CR for making my system outside the particular domain and open the port on the system so that it would post the request using webservice client. You can consult to your (infrastructure management team who are basically installing s/w solving system related issue)

One more thing is that most of the company use microsoft based proxy. So if u can use proxy bipassing code (NTLM based) . and use that for testing perpous but that would be a through away code because any way proxy bipassing code should not go to production